# How to add new data in an Item´s property of a DynamoDB´s table withouth overwriting the previous data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Currently I am putting the `srcPhoto` string into the `photos` property of a certain Item in my DynamoDB´s table. The problem is each time I do it, it completely overwrites the previous string. So basically I always have only one string (one piece of data) in the property `photos` in my table. My intention would be to add `srcPhoto`, but withouth deleting the previous one.

This is my code currently:

```js
let scanningParameters = {
        Key: {
            "site": folderName
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set photos = :photos",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":photos": [
             srcPhoto
             ]
        },
        TableName: 'Galleries'
    }
    
    return docClient
    .update(scanningParameters)
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }})
```

Edit: Solved following this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39601095/10708260

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ADD` action instead of `SET`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD

Here is the doc for the CLI. Its pretty self explanatory in terms of doing it in Javascript.

### Adding Elements to a Set

Assume that the Color attribute does not exist. The following AWS CLI example sets Color to a string set with two elements.

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
--table-name ProductCatalog \
--key '{"Id":{"N":"789"}}' \
--update-expression "ADD Color :c" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":c": {"SS":["Orange", "Purple"]}}' \
--return-values ALL_NEW
```

Now that Color exists, you can add more elements to it.

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
--table-name ProductCatalog \
--key '{"Id":{"N":"789"}}' \
--update-expression "ADD Color :c" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":c": {"SS":["Yellow", "Green", "Blue"]}}' \
--return-values ALL_NEW
```

Comment: Wow, that seems exactly what I need. I´m currently using just Lambda functions. And I just changed "set" by "add" in UpdateExpression but it gave an error. I think it´s because Taking a look at the docs I see that I should put "add Photos :c" instead of "set photos = :photos" However this is what I don´t understand. Color is a property, what is ":c" then? I´m not sure what I should put below in the ExpressionAttributeValues

Comment: :c is a value for the property that you define. You can use :photos, thats no problem. Is srcPhoto a string? Remove the brackets around it.

Comment: Yes, it is a string

Comment: I updated the code in the OP of what I changed, what brackets do you mean? For now in this last try I have changed "set photos = :photos" for "add photos :photos".

Comment: ":photos": {"SS": [srcPhoto ]} <- probably something like that